# Cannot use design-system-react

Tags: reactjs, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

When I try to user design-system-react, errors happen like below:
ReferenceError: IconSettings is not defined
IconSettings include in the library so it should be used without definition.

```
<script type="text/babel">

  class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <IconSettings iconPath="/assets/icons">
          <AlertContainer>
            <Alert
              icon={<Icon category="utility" name="user" />}
              labels={{
                heading: 'Logged in as John Smith (johnsmith@acme.com).',
                headingLink: 'Log out',
              }}
              onClickHeadingLink={() => {
                console.log('Link clicked.');
              }}
            />
          </AlertContainer>
        </IconSettings>
      );
    }
  }

  Example.displayName = 'AlertExample';

  ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));


</script>
```

Comment: you need to import IconSettings, the same as (probably) AlertContainer, Alert and so on. something like this i'd assume (from the docs) `import IconSettings from '@salesforce/design-system-react/components/icon-settings` check here: https://github.com/salesforce/design-system-react

Comment: Thank you for your kindly support.
I am using a bundled version of Design System React, reading it with CDN.
How can I import iconSettings?

Comment: have you tried adding the line i wrote in my last comment before the class declaration? 
and how are you using/ loading react? it should be similar

Comment: I wrote it but error happens... "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". I am loading react with code "<apex:includeScript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></apex:includeScript>"

Comment: maybe try that for design system too?

Comment: Yes!! It is loaded from static resources. <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.design_system_react)}" />

Comment: i'm not quite sure if you want to tell me, that you're already doing that, or that it now finally works...

Comment: I am loading design-system-react with CDN but cannot use its components...

Comment: maybe there's an error with you loading the resource? I'm not that familiar with the syntax but is there a way for you to check if you really loaded dsr? 
here it also declares a js-file in the !URLFOR part https://www.brcline.com/blog/using-jquery-in-visualforce

Comment: `value="{!URLFOR($Resource.scripts, '/jQuery.js')}"` from the example above... you seem to omit the second parameter?

Comment: This syntax is the way to load Javascript file in Visualforce page. A bundled version of Design System React should be loaded but cannot use their components...

Comment: well, my example was that syntax too, no? 
and i understand that you can't use the components, i'm just wondering if your bundled version is even correctly loaded? can you check that? in your network devtools. or add more code so i don't have to stumble in the dark here

Comment: I tried not to omit the second parameter but error continues...

Comment: have you checked if it is even loaded?

Comment: I confirmed it is loaded correctly in Chrome dev console.
So I cannot understand why cannot use components

Comment: maybe because your react stuff is minimized and everything is in one place, that why it's working but that does not apply for design-system-react? i can't really help you with just the script tag and react code honestly

Comment: OK, I am trying to search bugs!
Thank you so much for your help.